# How do I disable function when triggerExit2D?

Tags: unity

I want to add a system when the player moves to the door, the scene changed but if the player walks away from the door the function that I call disables it. so I put `OnTriggerEnter2D` and `OnTriggerExit2D` to make that. The issue is once the triggerExit the bool return false but not the function.

so this my script:

```cs
     private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            finish = true;

            if (finish)
                StartCoroutine(WaitForChangeScene());
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            finish = false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator WaitForChangeScene()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);

    }
```

Comment: You do not need to check inside OnTriggerEnter2D if finish is true since it is always true at this point. But you can check inside WaitForChangeScene if it is still true by the time your wait is over and only then load the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cancel the coroutine `WaitForChangeScene` in the `OnTriggerExit2D` function. Add a variable to hold the coroutine then you can use that variable to start and stop the coroutine.

```
private IEnumerator coroutine;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        //finish = true;
        coroutine = WaitForChangeScene()
        //if (finish)
            StartCoroutine(coroutine);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        //finish = false;
        StopCoroutine(coroutine);
    }
}

public IEnumerator WaitForChangeScene()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
}
```

You're only setting the finish variable to false in `OnTriggerExit2D` but not doing anything with it. In `OnTriggerEnter2D` you are checking the finish variable straight after setting it to true so it will always be true.

Comment: How can I miss this? thank you this helps me out .